# MediaWiki bot automatically copying content from external websites

Tags: content-management-system, automation, mediawiki, copy-paste, bots

I am trying to find a MediaWiki bot or extension that would do the following:

I sometimes copy external content to MediaWiki to display it in proper context and to make it searchable. That is not very DRY.

I would like to keep a live link to the original content using a special tag and have a bot  update the MediaWiki page if the original content changes.

For instance, the snippet could be a configuration file in Subversion that I want to reference in documentation. I would like to do something like:

```
<external-content 
    url="http://svn/config.txt" 
    start="#begin snippet" 
    end="#end snippet">
</external-content>
```

The MediaWiki bot would download `http://svn/config.txt`, retain everything between the `#begin snippet` and `#end snippet` comments, and paste the result right between the external-content tags.

This way I can be sure that as I change the `config.txt`, my MediaWiki documentation stays in sync.

There are numerous other uses. I am not looking only into referencing Subversion content, there are many other web-based systems with data I would like to integrate in this manner.

Does anyone know of a bot that would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do this with a MediaWiki [parser tag extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTag_extensions).  In fact, the ["Include" extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aInclude) seems to do something very much like what you're asking for.

Comment: Sweet! I knew something like this must exist in one form or another!

Comment: Actually, the include extension is not what I am looking for. The extension will download the data and render it as a part of the page. What I want is to actually INSERT the data directly into the wiki database, so it can be searchable and safe in case the original page goes down.

Comment: Hmm, in that you do need a bot, or something very much like one.  Basically, you need some way to run a script whenever the original content changes (or poll the original page at regular intervals if you can't do that).  Once you solve that, writing a bot to insert the content into a MediaWiki page through the [edit API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Edit) should be pretty simple.